# Change dataframe using a dropdown menu in Plotly

Tags: python, plotly

I want to show a single plotly figure where the showed dataframe must change according to a dropdown menu.
I've tried the following code but the only I see changing is the title not the data showed.
My intention is to show either data1 or data2.

```
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.io as pio

data1 = {'x': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 'y': [10, 15, 13, 17, 20]}
data2 = {'x': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 'y': [5, 8, 9, 12, 10]}

fig = px.line(data1, x='x', y='y', title="Data 1")
# fig.add_scatter(x=data2['x'], y=data2['y'], mode='lines')

fig.update_layout(
    updatemenus=[
        dict(
            active=0,
            buttons=list([
                dict(label="Data1",
                     method="update",
                     args=[
                         { "visible": [True]},
                           {
                               "title": "Data 1",
                               "data_frame":data1
                            },
                           ]),
                dict(label="Data2",
                     method="update",
                     args=[
                         { "visible": [True]},
                         {
                               "title": "Data 2",
                               "data_frame":data2
                         }
                           ]),
            ]),
        )
    ])

fig.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this works:

```py
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.io as pio

data1 = {'x': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 'y': [10, 15, 13, 17, 20]}
data2 = {'x': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 'y': [5, 8, 9, 12, 10]}
data3 = {'x': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 'y': [1, 2, 1, 2, 2]}

fig = px.line(data1, x='x', y='y', title="Data 1")
fig.add_scatter(x=data2['x'], y=data2['y'], mode='lines')
fig.add_scatter(x=data3['x'], y=data3['y'], mode='lines')

fig.update_traces(visible=False)
fig.data[0].visible = True

steps = []
for i in range(len(fig.data)):
    step = dict(
        method="update",
        label="Data #" + str(i),
        args=[{"visible": [False] * len(fig.data)},
              {"title": "Slider switched to step: " + str(i)}],
    )
    step["args"][0]["visible"][i] = True
    steps.append(step)

sliders = [dict(
    active=0,
    buttons=steps
)]

fig.update_layout(updatemenus=sliders)

fig.show()
```

Comment: Thanks maxim
this works but I'm not sure if this really fits what I need. Let me develop a bit more. I put a simple example with two similar dataframes but in my real scenario I'm going to have tens of dataframes with different number of traces and 'color'. I wanted to create 4, 6 'void' frames with a dropdown selection , with each selection I expected to change, dataframe, x, y, color and title. Do you know if it is possible without creating a figure with tons of traces and then deal with the visible. I think the code can get a bit complicated doing that way